¿Como puedo acceder a la información en mi JWT para cambiar la respuesta en mi controlador de .NET?
Tengo el siguiente controlador en mi API de .NET
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] OrderQueryFilters filters)
    {
        var pagePrev = filters.PageNumber != 1 ? filters.PageNumber - 1 : 1;
        var pageNext = filters.PageNumber + 1;
        var AllOrders = _service.GetAll(filters);
        var AllOrdersDTO = _map.Map<IEnumerable<OrderBasicDTO>>(AllOrders);
        Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Date", filters.Date?.ToShortDateString()},
            {"MinPrice", filters.MinPrice.ToString()},
            {"MaxPrice", filters.MaxPrice.ToString() },
            {"MaxDate", filters.MaxDate?.ToShortDateString() },
            {"MinDate", filters.MinDate?.ToShortDateString()},
            {"PageSize", filters.PageSize == 0 ? "1" : filters.PageSize.ToString() }
        };
        var previousQueryParams = queryParams;
        previousQueryParams["PageNumber"] = AllOrders.hasPreviousPage == false ? "false" : pagePrev.ToString();
        var previousParamsURL = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("https://apifakerubikstore.azurewebsites.net/api/Order", previousQueryParams);

        var nextQueryParams = queryParams;
        nextQueryParams["PageNumber"] = AllOrders.hasNextPage == true ? pageNext.ToString() : "false";
        var nextParamsURL = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("https://apifakerubikstore.azurewebsites.net/api/Order", nextQueryParams);
        MetaData metaData = new MetaData()
        {
            CurrentPage = AllOrders.CurrentPage,
            HasNextPage = AllOrders.hasNextPage,
            HasPreviousPage = AllOrders.hasPreviousPage,
            PageSize = AllOrders.PageSize,
            TotalCount = AllOrders.PageCount,
            TotalPage = AllOrders.TotalPages,
            NextPageURL = _uriService.GetPaginationOrder(filters, nextParamsURL).ToString(),
            PreviousPageURL = _uriService.GetPaginationOrder(filters, previousParamsURL).ToString()
        };
        var response = new ResponsePagination<IEnumerable<OrderBasicDTO>>(AllOrdersDTO,
            "this all Orders filtered",
            200, metaData);
        return Ok(response);
    }

Como pueden observar, estoy atendiendo una solicitud Get donde devuelvo todos los registros paginando mi respuesta y con unos filtros.
Quiero reutilizar esta lógica para dar respuestas un poco diferente según sea el rol del usuario, de tal forma que si es un Admin o vendedor le retornen todas las órdenes, si es un comprador, que le retornen solo las que le pertenecen a él.
Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo acceder al JWT desde mi controlador para realizar esto?
